# Char* в System::string в c++-cli

Tags: c++-cli

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Выражение

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr(84))
```

должно, насколько я понимаю, выдавать строку из одной английской буквы "T", согласно Ascii-таблице:

[image]

У меня получается "84".

Я перепробовал все способы, которые сумел найти, знаю все вопросы об этом наизусть.

Есть ли какой-то способ, чтобы преобразовать `int` в `char`, чтобы он выводил *символ* по Ascii-коду, а не просто число?

Следующие варианты также **не помогли:**

```
String^ strNew = gcnew String(charStriing[0]);
```

```
str += wchar_t(ch[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, то что выводится 84 у вас - это удача.

```
System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi
```

принимает IntPtr на неуправляемую строку(именно строку, т.е. будет скопировано все до нуль-терминированного символа).

Вы же передаете туда `IntPtr(84)`. Это не указатель на на ячейку в памяти со значением `84`, а указатель на ячейку с адресом `84`. Что там находится - большой вопрос.

У вас бы сработало что-то вроде

```
char some_char[2] = {84, '\0' };
auto ptr = IntPtr(&some_char);
System::String^ str = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
```

В вашем случае достаточно сделать так:

```
char unmanaged_char = 84;
System::Char managed_char(unmanaged_char);
```

Ну или

```
System::Char managed_char(84);
```